# How to load an iframe when the main content is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo, arcgis

I'm not a great expert in programming and am having trouble loading an iframe in my main page.

The main page and the iframe are not on the same domain, but I can modify each one. My main page is managed by a CMS (Joomla) and my Iframe is a JavaScript application that use ArcGIS API (version 3.7) and consequently Dojo (version 1.9).

I want to load JavaScript code in my iframe only when the main page is completly loaded.

Here is the JS code of my iframe :

```
require([
  "esri/map",
  "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) { 
    var map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");
    ...
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help !
Magalie.

Answer (score 0):

I practically think, for you to know that the iframe has completely loaded, u will need to interact with the iframe. Iframe would post a message when it has completed loading and this will be the point you need to capture..

As far as basic iframe related events exist, u only get the onLoad event which is when the iframe has started loading, not the completion of loading.

Comment: I think @Magalie is asking how to let the iframe know the main page is loaded, not the other way around. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Javascript's `postMessage` functionality - there's a good example of passing message back and forth across an iframe [here](http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes). When your parent document is finished loading, you can tell the iframe about it using:

```
iframe = document.getElementById('content');
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('finished_loading', 'http://remote-domain.com');
```

and the iframe can listen using:

```
window.addEventListener('message', doStuffOnceParentLoaded, false);
```

or

```
window.attachEvent("onmessage", doStuffOnceParentLoaded, false);
```

in IE because standards are for other people.

Bear in mind you MAY end up with weird inconsistent timing issues - if your iframe finishes loading after the parent loads, it may not register to listen to the event before it is sent.

Comment: Sorry for my silence and thanks for your answers.
I work on several projects at the same time ! I'll test quickly what you suggest me and give you a return.